# How to mock database connection in .net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I need to mock database connection and then call a method to return the value.

I created moq data but i am not sure how to mock database connection.

```
private void SetupUserRepository()
{
    var firstname = "FirstName1";
    var _lastName = "LastName1";
    var _userName = "FirstName1.LastName1@warburgpincus.com";
    var _email = "FirstName1.LastName1@warburgpincus.com";
    var User = new User { FirstName = firstname, LastName = _lastName, Username = _userName,Email = _email};
   var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
       // mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetOne(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync((string section, CancellationToken token) => moqData.contentControls.FirstOrDefault(a => a.InternalControlName == section));
   // mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetOne(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
    //var x = moqData.userDetails.First(a => a.Username == _userName);
    mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetOne(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(moqData.userDetails.First(a => a.Username == _userName));
    UserRepository test = new UserRepository(mockUserRepository.Object,null,null);
    var result = test.GetOne(_userName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
    ///var repo = new UserRepository(mockUserRepository.Object,null,null);
    //var actual = await repo.GetOne(_userName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
    Assert.Same(User, result);
}
```

And in the controller class below is the parameters that are needed

```
public UserRepository(ValuationsReportingContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<UserRepository> logger) : base(context, httpContextAccessor)
{
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    claimsPrincipal = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User;
}
```

Need to get the data from the list instead of database

```
UserRepository test = new UserRepository(mockUserRepository.Object,null,null);
```

this line is throwing an error as it is expecting an dbcontext.

Comment: what you're trying to do is mock the db context but what you're actually doing is creating a mock of your UserRepository and trying to inject that into your actual UserRepository.  

You can't mock a database.  Technically, in a unit test, you wouldn't want to as it's an external dependency.  You should instead create a mock user repository and call that for data, which you're close to doing, but which renders your above test fairly useless as all it would be testing is the Moq framework's ability to do what you told it to do.  It wouldn't be testing your code.

Comment: @Mike Basically i need to unit test 1 method which is connected to database. So what will be the best option for this and in my unit testing i dont want to connect to database

Comment: why do you pass fake `IUserRepository` into the real `UserRepository`? It doesn't make sense for me. Why can't you do something like `var result = mockUserRepository.Object.GetOne(_userName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()) `?

Comment: @mtkachenko Thanks for the help it solves my issue

Comment: @harshamullangi Good to hear! Mark my answer as correct then.

Comment: You are basically trying to test that the mock framework does what it is suppose to do. This post is unclear as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @harshamullangi Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use real implementation of `UserRepository`. Instead use your `IUserRepository` mock:

```
var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
...
var result = mockUserRepository.Object.GetOne(_userName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
```